# My ForeignKey is displayed as model object when I use it as a dropdown in form in django

Tags: object, django-models, django-forms, model, foreign-keys

```
class JobsModel(models.Model):
    company=models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfileModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    job_role=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    job_description=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    salary=models.IntegerField()
    requirements=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    job_type=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now,null=True)


class JobsModel(models.Model):
    company=models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfileModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    job_role=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    job_description=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    salary=models.IntegerField()
    requirements=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    job_type=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now,null=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBn4K.jpg)

Comment: This is *not* a question. You should explain *what* you aim to do, what you tried, and what is not working. See [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thankyou, I got ny problem solved. Actually i used  a ForeignKey for a field in one of my model. And i created a form using that model. Since i didnt give def__str__(self) : return self. (Model name) i was not getting the actual name in the dropdown of the form when i rendered the form in the html page. Since there was more than one field in the ForeignKey Model.